# Why does property 'find' not exist on my array using // @ts-check on Javascript in VS Code? (2018, typescript 2.7x)

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

** update

```
console.log(Array.isArray(primaryNumberFemales)); // true
```

and I export it with:

```
export {
  primaryNumberFemales,
};
```

** end update

I have an array (which is of course type object) that looks like this:

```
const primaryNumberFemales = [{
  name: 'Sky',
  number: 6,
  duality: 'Yang',
  complexity: 'Complex',
  year: [1910,
    1919,
    1928,
    1937,
    1946,
    1955,
    1964,
    1973,
    1982,
    1991,
    2000,
    2009,
    2018,
  ],
},
{
  name: 'Lake',
  number: 7,
  duality: 'Yin',
  complexity: 'Simple',
  year: [1911,
    1920,
    1929,
    1938,
    1947,
    1956,
    1965,
    1974,
    1983,
    1992,
    2001,
    2010,
    2019,
  ],
},
];
```

Which I import with:

```
import {
  primaryNumberFemales,
} from './data';
```

and confirm it is an object after importing (so nothing funny has gone on somehow) with:

```
console.log(typeof primaryNumberFemales); // object
```

i want to type check my JS in VS Code 1.20.1 so add:

// @ts-check

now with the code below i get an error in the linter for every instance of `find`, the program works fine!:

```
  return (gender === 'F') ? {
    primaryNumber: (primaryNumberFemales.find(includesYearOfBirth) || {}).number,
    typeOfExpression: (primaryNumberFemales.find(includesYearOfBirth) || {}).name,
  } : {
    primaryNumber: (primaryNumberMales.find(includesYearOfBirth) || {}).number,
    typeOfExpression: (primaryNumberMales.find(includesYearOfBirth) || {}).name,
  };
```

**Property 'find' does not exist on type '{ [x: string]: any; name: string; number: number; duality: string; complexity: string; year: numb...'.**

I know Array.prototype.find() is es6, and it was not supported in the past (plenty of posts on that here before), but it should definitely be supported now. Is there something wrong with my code, or is this some kind of bug? THANKS!

Comment: `primaryNumberFemales` does not have an attribute named `find` - thus this cannot work

Comment: erm, @messerbill - if it is an Array it does (in ES6 at least)

Comment: `but it should definitely be supported now` - which environment? browser? which browser? IE, then no - you may want a polyfill

Comment: @JaromandaX does the type `{ [x: string]: any; name: string; number: number; duality: string; complexity: string; year: numb...` looks like an array for you? :)

Comment: No ... does `const primaryNumberFemales = [{ .... }]` look like an array to you?

Comment: @messerbill  `looks like an array for you? :` Of course not, but that where the problem lies, looking at the code it should be returning an array.  Find out why it thinks it's an object, problem solved.  Maybe we need to see what the `export` looks like.

Comment: perhaps if the OP could show **how** it's **exported**

Comment: @JaromandaX bonne point!

Comment: @messerbill - didn't even read the error, so, I see your point too

Comment: instead of `console.log(typeof primaryNumberFemales);` try `console.log(Array.isArray(primaryNumberFemales));`

Comment: I updated the post... and the environment we are talking about is purely the vs code linter. Righ now the repo is reflecting the problem, you can see the entire code base if that helps https://github.com/Else-Web-Development/natural-expression-calculator-application/blob/master/src/main.js

Comment: @Keith did you get a chance to check out my updated answer?

Comment: `import { primaryNumberFemales,}`  Is that extra comma deliberate, it won't error Javascript, but I wonder if it might confuse TS.

Comment: @Keith I actually cut down my code in the example to make it easier to see the problem, the actual export has other things as well, you can see it right at the bottom here https://github.com/Else-Web-Development/natural-expression-calculator-application/blob/master/src/data.js

Answer (score 0):

If I parse the code in my head, when I'm looking at this expression:

```
import { primaryNumberFemales } from './data';
```

I'm wondering how the error isn't here, as your module doesn't export this constant. To fix this, I would use the `export` keyword:

```
export const primaryNumberFemales = [{
    name: 'Sky',
    number: 6,
    duality: 'Yang',
    complexity: 'Complex',
    year: [1910,
      1919,
      1928,
      1937,
      1946,
      1955,
      1964,
      1973,
      1982,
      1991,
      2000,
      2009,
      2018,
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'Lake',
    number: 7,
    duality: 'Yin',
    complexity: 'Simple',
    year: [1911,
      1920,
      1929,
      1938,
      1947,
      1956,
      1965,
      1974,
      1983,
      1992,
      2001,
      2010,
      2019,
    ],
  },
  ];
```

If I run this example through the compiler it seems happy enough, I can use the `Array.find` method too. I have set my compiler to target `ES6`.

Comment: I do export it, I updated  my original post, sorry about not being more explicit. It is NOT that the program does not work, it is that VS Code's type script linter is showing an error.